# AppleScript: Checking a list for an existing item

Tags: list, duplicates, applescript

I can't figure out why this script is not working. I have a list of almost two thousand entries (categories) but there are many duplicates. I'm just trying to create a list of unique categories but I can't seem to get it to work.

Background: I am reading a CSV file that has a column titled: CATEGORIES. I read the file, use a newline delimiter to create an array of each entry, loop through the array, delimit again by the comma separator and get the content for the CATEGORIES column. Those entries could be a single category or multiple entered as `CAT1; CAT2` or just to be more annoying `CAT1 > CAT2`. Here's my code, I am ignoring the third instance of categories that can be returned (with the `>` symbol) for now until I get the code working.

```
...
set arrCategories to {}

set theCats to item 14 of arrThisLine
set oatd to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
set subCats to every text item of theCats
        
repeat with thisSubCat in subCats
    if thisSubCat does not contain ">" then
        if arrCategories contains thisSubCat then
        else
            copy thisSubCat to end of arrCategories
            log arrCategories
        end if
    end if
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oatd
```

The log looks like this, eventually there are thousands of entries in arrCategories (I have roughly 1000 line in the CSV to loop over)

```
(*Design*)
(*Design, Design*)
(*Design, Design, Design*)
(*Design, Design, Design, Design*)
(*Design, Design, Design, Design, Revenue*)
(*Design, Design, Design, Design, Revenue, Learning & Development*)
(*Design, Design, Design, Design, Revenue, Learning & Development,  Product & Engineering*)
(*Design, Design, Design, Design, Revenue, Learning & Development,  Product & Engineering, Product & Engineering*)
```

I am sure it is just something simple I am missing but I cannot figure out why it is not picking up the duplicates. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Yosemite or later systems you can avoid repeat loops using AppleScript Objective C:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite or later
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

-- .... INSERT HERE THE BEGINNING OF YOUR SCRIPT

set theCats to item 14 of arrThisLine
set oatd to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
set subCats to every text item of theCats
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oatd

-- remove items with ">"
set stringArray to current application's NSArray's arrayWithArray:subCats
set thePred to current application's NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:"!self  LIKE '*>*'"
set bList to (stringArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePred) as list

-- remove duplicates
set aSet to current application's NSOrderedSet's orderedSetWithArray:bList
set arrCategories to (aSet's array()) as list
```

I tested following script:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set theCats to {"Design", "Design", "Design > Design", "Revenue", "Learning & Development", "Product & Engineering", "Product & Engineering"}

-- remove duplicates, retaining list's order
set aSet to current application's NSOrderedSet's orderedSetWithArray:theCats
set aList to (aSet's array()) as list

-- remove strings with ">"
set stringArray to current application's NSArray's arrayWithArray:aList
set thePred to current application's NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:"!self  LIKE '*>*'"
set arrCategories to (stringArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePred) as list

--> {"Design","Revenue","Learning & Development","Product & Engineering"}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It's been years since I've done AS but I've been doing Mac desktop and mobile since 2007, didn't even know this. : D

Answer (score 1):

When using the `repeat with X in Y` form of the repeat statement, the loop variable X is actually a reference to an item in the list Y.  Depending on what you are doing, its contents may not get dereferenced.

If trying to do something like compare the loop variable to text, the comparison will fail because it will be to the reference itself rather than its value.  To be sure you are using the actual value, you can get the `contents` of the loop variable, or coerce it to the desired class before working with it, for example:

```
repeat with thisSubCat in subCats
   set thisSubCat to thisSubCat as text
   --
```